# Solve not returning anything

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following function:

```
test = D[(a - A)^2 + (b - B)^2 + (c - C)^2 + 
         ( a + b - (S + c) - D)^2 - λ1*a - λ2* b - λ3*c  - λ4*(a + b - (S + c)), 
        {{a, b, c}}]
```

Then I solve for `a,b,c`, and get:

```
solutions = Solve[Thread[test == 0], {a, b, c}]
```

So now, I plug the results of `a,b,c` back into test to remove `a,b,c` from my original equation and take the derivatives with respect to `Lambda1, Lambda2,Lambda3,Lambda4`. So I get the following:

```
results = 
 ExpandAll[
  D[(a - A)^2 + (b - B)^2 + (c - C)^2 + 
    ( a + b - (S + c) - D)^2 - λ1*a - λ2* b - λ3*c - λ4*( a + b - (S + c)) /. 
    solutions[[1]], {{λ1, λ2, λ3,  λ4}}]]
```

However, when I try to solve for `Lambda1, Lambda2,Lambda3,Lambda4`, I get nothing back:

```
lambdasolutions = Solve[Thread[ results == 0], {λ1, λ2, λ3, λ4}]
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do NOT use capitals for variable names.

Comment: @Histograms where did I use capitals? the A,B,C,D are constants.

Comment: Look at the following: [C](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/C.html?q=C); [D](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/D.html?q=D). In particular: you seem to know that `D[]` is a built in function, but then you used it as a constant as well!?

Comment: @Histograms ok I removed the capitals thanks. However, I am still getting nothing. Did you get a result when you ran it?

Comment: @kolonel I got nothing too. Perhaps there are no solutions.

Comment: @Nasser Okay I will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Reduce[ ]` instead of `Solve[ ]`

```
exp = (a - A)^2 + (b - B)^2 + (c - CC)^2 + (a + b - (S + c) - 
      DD)^2 - λ1*a - λ2*b - λ3* c - λ4*(a + b - (S + c));
test = D[exp, {{a, b, c}}];
solutions = Solve[Thread[test == 0], {a, b, c}];
results = ExpandAll[  D[exp /. solutions[[1]], {{λ1, λ2, λ3, λ4}}]];
lambdasolutions = Reduce[Thread[ results == 0], {λ1, λ2, λ3, λ4}]

(* S == 0 && λ2 == 2 A - 2 B + λ1 && λ3 == -2 A - 2 CC - λ1 && λ4 == -2 A - 2 DD - λ1 *)
```

Comment: should I interpret this as this solution could only hold if S == 0? Also thanks.

Comment: @kolonel there is no solution if `S != 0`

Comment: alright thank you sir.